# Does Google Map support <BalloonStyle><text> like Google Earth?

Tags: google-maps, styles, kml, balloon

I am uploading kmls into Google Map (not Google Earth).

My KMLs contain polygons (county borders).

There is a different "styleurl" for each county.   Right now I can control the content of the bubble via `<name>` and `<description>` from within the polygon's `<Placemark>` tags.   Instead I would like to control the bubble content from within the Style definition, using

`<BalloonStyle>`
   `<text>My custom text</text>`
`</BalloonStyle>`

Q1 Does Google map support these functions (my testing so far suggests "no")

Q2 Where could I have looked up this answer on my own before posting here?

Thanks!

Comment: @GeoCodeZip  Yes I saw that documented  but it appears to not work at all.  I made a test map, exported kml and tweaked the Google-generated text by adding "Test" 
    <BalloonStyle>    <text><![CDATA[Test <h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
in the style definition.   No change in the bubble..  Then I tweaked the name in the placemark tags and that did appear int he bubble.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements) `<BaloonStyle>` is partially supported by the API:

> `<BalloonStyle>`  partially   only `<text>` is supported